# pass random variables to function in pyspark while using withColumn

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a `data frame` in `pyspark`. It has columns `id` , `name`, `city` and `country`
I have a `list` that contains some `names` in it. I want to add a new column to the data frame called `test` if `name` is in list then `Y` else `N`.

I have done like below. I created a function to do this `operation`.

```
def new_column(df, list):
    df1 = df.withColumn('test', when(df.name.isin(list), "Y").otherwise('N'))
    return df1
```

Then I will invoke

```
new_df = new_column(df, list)
```

Then my `new_df` contains `test` column and populates values based on the `isin` condition specified.

Now I want to use this same function at different places in my script.

I have a list called `cities` that contains `city` names and list `to_visit` that contains `country` names.

Say I want to create multiple data frames with different new columns by checking some column in the data frame.

For example I want to do this.

```
In data frame check for column say city and populate new column city_visited.
In data frame check for column say country and populate new column bucket_list
```

In the above I created `new_df` then after doing some `transformations` I will have a data frame called `full_df`. on this `full_df` I want to populate `city_visited` column like below.

```
city_visited_df = new_column(full_df, cities)
```

Then on this `city_visited_df` I will do some `transformations` I will have a data frame called `secure_df`. on this `secure_df` I want to populate `bucket_list` column like below.

```
bucket_list_df = new_column(secure_df, to_visit)
```

Basically I want to do is to pass the column name I want to add and the column to check to the function.

```
def new_column(df, list, column_to_add, column_to_check):
    df1 = df.withColumn('column_to_add', when(df.column_to_check.isin(list), "Y").otherwise('N'))
    return df1
```

Is this possible. if it is possible how can I do that?

> edit based on @pault's comment

```
def new_column(df, list, column_to_add, column_to_check):
    df1 = df.withColumn('column_to_add', when(df[column_to_check].isin(list), "Y").otherwise('N'))
    return df1
```

I am getting below error.

```
NameError: name 'column_to_add' is not defined
```

Comment: instead of using the `.` operator, use square brackets. Turn `df.column_to_check.isin(some_list)` into `df[column_to_check].isin(some_list)` and avoid naming variables `list` as that conflicts with the builtin `list` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have define your variables.

```
column_to_add = 'secure_id'
column_to_check = 'device_model'
```

Your function will be like here

```
def new_column(df, list, column_to_add, column_to_check):
    df1 = df.withColumn(column_to_add, when(df[column_to_check].isin(list), "Y").otherwise('N'))
    return df1
```

Then invoke your function like

```
newer_df = new_column(df, list, column_to_add, column_to_check)
```

Then you won't get any errors